# Meta and # in a UK mac terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

In the mac terminal application there is a setting (preferences -> keyboard) that lets you set "use option as meta key". This is useful as a lot of unix boxes use `bash` as default shell and that has emacs keybindings `M-f` and `M-b` that let you skip words.

Problem is that on a Mac with a UK keyboard the `#` symbol is tricky to get to - normally it can  be typed with `alt-3`, but not if you are in a terminal and alt=meta.

Anyone have a nice way round this?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630643/inserting-character-in-os-x-terminal-when-using-option-as-meta-key/2630929#2630929

Answer (score 9):

I am using `zsh` and the following saved my day:

```
bindkey -s '^[3' \#
```

Comment: Awesome. I was trying `bindkey '\e3' '#'` and wondering why it didn't work; I missed the `-s` option, as defined on `man zshzle` line ~144: 'in-string out-string' remap. Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately when I'm in Vim alt-3 just jumps the cursor back one character.

Answer (score 7):

Set your keyboard language ( System Preferences->International->InputMenu ) to Australian

It is the same as UK except shift-3 gives #. You do lose the pound sign but if I do currency I use the ISO three character code GBP

Answer (score 3):

The Australian layout is identical as mentioned except # is mapped to Shift 3 and £ is mapped to Alt 3.
Swap to Aus and the swap your ALT behaviour. This has annoyed me for while especially as it is in a non UK position to start with.

Answer (score 3):

Earlier today I stumbled on a great solution to this on [Graeme Sutherland](http://grasuth.com/2010/11/03/remap-key-on-uk-keyboards/)'s blog so thought I'd summarise it here in case it disappears.

If you want to stick with the built-in Terminal and don't want to lose the £ sign, you can use [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele) roll your own keyboard layout to switch the section (§) key for hash instead. Quite a handy location for typing '#!' too :)

The keymap file Graeme created is [here](https://github.com/grasuth/britishlhash), but if you want to make your own you can simply take the British one as a base it's pretty straightforward to create the new keymap file.

1. Copy your new keymap file to `~/Library/Keyboard Layouts`
2. Go to System Preferences - Language & Text - Input Sources
3. Scroll down to 'British with # for §' (or whatever you put as its name in Ukelele) and check the box
4. Check 'Show Input menu in menu bar'
5. Click on the flag in your menu bar at the top of the screen and choose your new input source

This input source can then be used in all apps, or just the ones you want it for.

I appreciate this and the linked question are quite old but thought this might help someone else.

Answer (score 2):

`ESC` is another meta shortcut :). You don't have to keep pressing it though.

So in your situation, you might just need to press `ESC` once, and then press `alt-3`.

Comment: The following works on a UK keyboard layout in Mac OSX Terminal on Mavericks (10.9.4): **Tap** `ESC` once, then (*after* you've released `ESC`), press `alt-3`. I believe my Terminal has only the default configuration, no special changes needed.

Comment: To add to my [earlier comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517136/meta-and-in-a-uk-mac-terminal#comment38406609_1517244), ensure that `Terminal > Preferences > Use option as meta key` is **unchecked**

Answer (score 1):

See image to get the details as to how to setup a shortcut in your terminal and fly free

[image: Setup a shortcut in your terminal and fly free]

Answer (score 1):

Based on [ericteubert answer for zsh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4685657/1600422) for `bash` you `bind` the key, I've added this to my `.bash_profile`:

```sh
 bind '"\e3":"#"'
```

For vim you can add the following to your `.vimrc`

```sh
inoremap <ESC>3 #
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using iTerm2 and I was having this problem. With iTerm2 you can use the left alt key as a meta key, and the right as a normal key. So ralt-3 does the # key.

Answer (score 0):

Neovim (nvim) setting:

```
-- allows you to type option+3 on Mac keyboard to get a hash sign
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('i','<M-3>','#', { noremap=true })
-- also in command mode, so you can use # in filenames, regular expressions etc.
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('c','<M-3>','#', { noremap=true })
```

That's in addition to the bash config mentioned in other answers to get # working in general in the terminal:

```
 bind '"\e3":"#"'
```